# Использование файлов JS

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть мой проект html. У меня есть JS-код прям в `index.html`, но он громоздкий и я решил вынести его в отдельный файл. Но теперь появляется ошибка, которую я не в силах исправить: `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')`

index.html:

```html
<body>
  <script src="assets/js/random_desc.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = change_desc();
  </script>
  <!-- ... -->
  <div id="desc" class="header_desc">desc text</div>
 </body>
```

random_desc.js:

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function change_desc(){
      var result = getRandomInt(2);
      switch(result){
        case 0:
          document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML="Hello";
          break;
        case 1:
          document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML="world!";
          break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вызов, а присвоение ссылки.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = change_desc; // <---
  </script>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь мой код работает.